How to turn on warnings for C compiler 6.3.0 version?
I'm staring to learn C, and via help of youtube I could download 6.3.0 compiler version, though my textbook is referring to 4.3.3.
I'm purposefully trying to get warnings (as a task to learn to interpret them) for a Hello World program without getting an error, but I don't get any.
I took away return(0) and then took away the second quote mark in printf, but PowerShell just executes the program after compilation without giving me any warnings.
I tried -W, -Wall, -Wextra, -Wreturn-type and even found -Wdouble-promotion, but to no success.
Original code:
/*
 * program that writes 'hello world'
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
   return 0;
}

Program code for testing out warnings:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello, world!\n);
   /*  took away the second quote mark
    *  and the return(0) operation 
    *  to test warnings
    */
}

Compiling and running the program results in
> gcc -Wall -o warning hello_warning.c
PS C:\Users\sofya\OneDrive\Документы\программки> ./warning
Hello, world!

Instead of giving me as well some of the warnings my textbook suggests, such as:
warning: missing terminating " character


A good start is -Wall -Wextra, but for the full story see the documentation.

I think you mean the 6.3.0 version of GCC. C itself doesn't have a version 6.3.0.

"C 6.3.0 version" - There's no such thing. There may be a 6.3.0 version of your C compiler, but that's not the same as the language version.

But to know what your problem is we need you to [edit] your question to show us the actual program you try to build, and how you build it. Please copy-paste it all as text.

What warnings are you expecting?  Why are you expecting these warnings?  If your code is correct, you shouldn't expect any warnings.

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

How can a missing " be a warning? The code can't be parsed correctly without it. The compiler can't decide it should go here and generate an executable with a warning.

Removing the return from main() is conforming, and should not generate warnings or errors. The int main() is the only non-void function that is not required to explicitly return a value.

@WeatherVane okay, got it. I only was trying to get it because the textbook is referring to getting warning: control reaches end of non-void function and I got confused and thought I was doing something wrong.

@JesperJuhl thank you! That did the job. Though I don't understand why -Wall and -Wexrtra wouldn't work on their own.

The syntax error you're provoking by omitting the closing " invariably results in a compilation error and, crucially, produces no output file and leaves a preexisting one alone.
Your symptom implies that you initially compiled a syntactically correct version of your program, followed by failed compilation due to the syntax error, causing subsequent invocation of ./warning to invoke the binary resulting from the earlier compilation of the syntactically correct program version.

As for expecting warnings to surface during compilation, building on the helpful comments:

Even with all warnings enabled (-Wall -Wextra), no warning is emitted if you remove a return statement from the main() function, specifically:

As Weather Vane notes:

Removing the return from main() is conforming, and should not generate warnings or errors. int main() is the only non-void function that is not required to explicitly return a value.




Thus, if you added, say, int other() { } to your program, you would see a warning, namely:

warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]

Note that warning -Wreturn-type is implied by -Wall, whereas -Wextra enables additional warnings.





Thank you, now I understand! Your additional notes were especially helpful.
